# What is the opposite of 'gravitas'?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm having difficulty coming up with a valid antonym for *gravitas*.

Online searches return results like superficiality, cheerfulness, frivolity, facetiousness etc. which don't work for me. They seem to be opposites of *gravitas* as it is understood by the person who has it.

As in, "We need to undertake this project with gravitas", "he carried himself with gravitas".

This is taken to mean *seriousness*.

There's another sense of the word, as the quality of a person having gravitas. In this case, the things they say and do are given significance because of 
 *gravitas*.

What if what someone has to say is automatically disregarded because of... the opposite of gravitas.

What would that word be?

Comment: I wish the answer was "anti-gravitas"...

Comment: It might be helpful to provide example sentences where your particular sense is used. As I read your question, the example sentences you show are of a sense  you *don't* want. -- I'm also unclear on the distinction in senses you seem to be making. You might want to clarify that, and example sentences of each (clearly labeled) can help.

Comment: Did you come up with "carried himself with gravitas"? I would say: He displayed or had gravitas. Carrying oneself is slightly dated, isn't it? Maybe ok in writing...

Comment: @Lambie I'd say 'gravitas' is a fairly old-fashioned word.

Comment: "flibbertigibbetosity"

Comment: @GregLee I so want that to be a real word.

Comment: Maybe it’s flibbertigibbetas

Comment: Your sample sentences work with 'gravitas' but you wouldn't want someone to "undertake a project with <the opposite of gravitas>" - Please can you give an example sentence where you would actually use your desired word? Then we can see what fits.

Comment: @AJFaraday Really? I wouldn't say it's old-fashioned at all. It's just that it's used mostly in more formal contexts, such as writing or criticism, and that hasn't changed for a long time. Just because you don't hear a word in everyday speech doesn't mean it's old-fashioned.

Comment: Language has no law comparable to Newton's third law of motion, which says that "for every action there has to be an equal and opposite reaction". English words are not required to have antonyms.

Comment: @WS2 I’m mostly looking for a way to express an idea.

Comment: @AJFaraday It is an interesting word, of 20C coinage. The earliest reference in the OED is from 1924. But the OED provides no meaning for it, only examples of its use. My "Shorter OED" defines its meaning as "Solemn demeanour, seriousness". But I sense that it has come to mean something more than that. A person with a lot of "gravitas", I would suggest carries things like "respect", "importance", "dignity", "influence" etc. as well as the OED's proposed "solemnity". Interestingly, the Hachette, provides the French equivalent as "envergure", which is related to "wingspan" and "large scale".

Comment: @Pam it's a perfectly good word. Somebody with a surfeit of anti-gravitas is very easy to imagine.

Comment: @nigel222 easy to imagine, perhaps. But not easy to notice.

Comment: @AJFAraday if we accept that levity is the common form, then it's the person who habitually derails or subverts  any important conversation to humorous effect the moment he opens his mouth (or perhaps just by rolling his eyes). Hard to miss.

Comment: @nigel222 That's not what I'm trying to describe. I'm not interested in someone who isn't taken seriously because they don't take things seriously. I'm trying to describe someone who doesn't get taken seriously because OTHERS don't take them seriously.

Comment: " Au jus",, obviously!

Answer (score 134):

You could try [*levity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levity):

> **Levity** may refer to
>
> - a sense of amusement, the opposite of gravitas

Comment: Weird quirk: Latin does have the word *levitas*, which would be a direct contrast to *gravitas*. However, because the Latin form is part of what gives *gravitas* its gravitas, it would feel odd or quirky to use *levitas* in the same way. Hence *levity* (comp. gravity) is a great choice.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin That's a beautiful irony. I wonder whether there's a word for this situation!

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin If "levity" has too much gravitas, one could substitute "levi-OHHHH-sa" and wave a little stick.

Comment: What is the word for someone who with levity and frivolity is deadly serious?

Comment: The oddity and quirkiness of _levitas_ makes it kinda perfect for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon - Big time. I'm totally filing it away...

Answer (score 38):

There is nothing wrong with the word '**frivolity**', as you pointed out. It actually means '*lack of seriousness*'. The word 'frivolity' comes from the Latin word 'frivolus', and is a synonym for 'levity', which is directly opposite to the word 'serious'.

**Frivolity** (noun): the quality or state of being ***frivolous***.

Merriam-Webster defines frivolous (adj.) as,

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frivolous

> **2.a:** lacking in seriousness
>
> > His frequent frivolous behavior in the meeting is a big concern.

Comment: Frivolity doesn't usually refer to the way someone carries themself, which is a typical use of *gravitas*.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey unfortunately, we can't say frivolitas or levitas.

Answer (score 12):

***Flippancy***, perhaps?

*Flippant* - Displaying unbecoming levity in the consideration of serious subjects or in behaviour to persons entitled to respect. (OED)

Answer (score 9):

I generally agree that levity is a pretty direct antonym of gravitas, but "he carried himself with levity" doesn't sound right. So I'll suggest

**insouciance**
n.  Blithe lack of concern; nonchalance.

Comment: I guess I think of "insouciance" as a positive - an attractive characteristic, rather than in inappropriate light-mindedness.

Comment: Lack of gravitas can be positive. It depends on context.

Answer (score 4):

What about [**apathy**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/apathy)?

> 1. absence or suppression of passion, emotion, or excitement.
> 2. lack of interest in or concern for things that others find moving or exciting.

Comment: The Stoic tradition believed strongly in both *gravitas* and *apatheia*. While modern apathy has different connotations, I still see *gravitas* as having a cool relaxed indifference that bears some resemblence to apathy.

Answer (score 3):

**Carelessness**
[kair-lis]
adjective

1) not paying enough attention to what one does

2) not exact, accurate, or thorough:
careless work.

2) done or said heedlessly or negligently; unconsidered:

4) not caring or troubling; having no care or concern; unconcerned (usually followed by of, about, or in)

5) possessed or caused without effort or art; unstudied

6) Archaic . free from anxiety.

[Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/carelessness)

Answer (score 3):

### Triviality

The [ODO definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/triviality) of 'triviality' states:

> Lack of seriousness or importance; insignificance.

Here are ODO examples of usage:

> ‘the mediocrity and **triviality** of current popular culture’
>
> ‘the relentlessness of his **triviality** is grating’

So in your examples, we might have:

> We need to undertake this project **without triviality**,
>
> He carried himself **in a trivial fashion**.

What you are getting at is, I think, a kind of weightlessness, and 'ungroundedness' in a person or project, which leads to a desire to avoid or disregard them.

Answer (score 3):

Lightweight.

From the Oxford Am.Dictionary:

2 
• informal a person of little importance or influence, especially in a particular sphere: *he was regarded as a political lightweight.*

Answer (score 2):

Another option: **nonchalance**

> > the state or quality of being nonchalant; cool indifference or lack of concern; casualness.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonchalance

Comment: Nonchalance is still an attitude, as opposed to a quality. I couldn't imagine saying "Nobody will listen to me, I've just got too much nonchalance".

Comment: Probably not, but I could imagine it as an adjective “Why won’t anyone take me seriously?” “Well, you are kind of nonchalant when you present.”

Answer (score 2):

Consider: **mercuriality**.

> mercuriality
>
> 1. the state or quality of having a lively, fickle, volatile, or erratic attitude or character.
> 2. an instance of such behavior. — mercurial, adj.

[The Free Dictionary.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mercuriality)

Comment: I don't think that fits. While a mercurial temperament is lacking in gravitas, it isn't a polar opposite -- "gravitas" doesn't imply a decisive, slow-moving, or predictable nature, nor does "mercurial" imply frivolity.

Answer (score 2):

How about **vacuity**, **silliness**, or **buffoonery**?

Comment: foolishness, senselessness

Comment: insincerity, flakiness, fishiness

Comment: You should support your answer by citing, e.g., dictionary definitions for your suggestions.

Comment: I think 'vacuity' might be the best answer of all. But it needs somebody to propose it with a dictionary definition, usage example etc.

Answer (score 2):

> This is taken to mean *seriousness*.
>
> [...]
>
> There's another sense of the word, as the quality of a person having gravitas. In this case, the things they say and do are given significance because of *gravitas*.

The specific use of "gravitas", this sense of possessing gravitas lending weight or importance to a person leads me to believe you may be extending the meaning of the phrase "air of gravitas" to "gravitas" itself. I therefore believe you are looking for

**insignificance**, the quality or state of being [insignificant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insignificant), which is itself defined as

> not significant: such as
>
> a : lacking meaning or import
>
> b : small in size, quantity, or number
>
> **c : not worth considering : unimportant**
>
> **d : lacking weight, position, or influence : contemptible**

[(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insignificance)

To put it in context from your question:

> What if what someone has to say is automatically disregarded because

of their **insignificance**?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest inane, inanity.

Google tells me about inane:
mid 16th century: from Latin inanis ‘empty, vain’.

Inanity [(From merriam-webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inanity)
the quality or state of being inane: such as
a : lack of substance : emptiness
b : vapid, pointless, or fatuous character : shallowness

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ['foppery'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foppery)?   aka: *foolish character or action*

> "The entire exercise was laden with foppery, and as a result lacked any sense of gravitas."

Depending on the actual sentence structure, it could be 'foppish'.

> "Nobody will listen to me, I'm far too foppish."

Comment: That's over the moon here,isn't it? :)

Comment: Seriously check this word in urbandictionary.com before you use it about a co-worker!

Comment: @CCTO I couldn't find an entry for 'foppery' in urban dictionary, and similar entries for words starting with 'fop' don't seem widely used.  'foppish' does have an entry meaning basically 'effeminate'

Comment: @Daniel: you are right, I was sloppy. It's the form "foppish" that's in urbandictionary, confirming my initial reaction that "foppery" would, by many speakers, be taken to imply effeminacy. The actual form "foppery" may be less common, in any usage, but I'd be prepared for many people to apply the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

As far as attractive force is concerned, the obvious opposite is

> repulsiveness

An easier word that better fits the theme of levity (proposed above) would be

> **ease**

The opposite of a grave situation that may be potentially underestimated with regards to its gravitas, would be an easy situation, after all.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of gravitas in your example, the gravitas is a externally perceived quality of the person in question.

**Insignificance** would be the opposite of the meaning of gravitas in your example. The problem with this, at least for me:

1. What she says carries a lot of weight, because of her gravitas.
2. What she says is automatically disregarded, because of her insignificance.

In 1., the attribution is implicitly a perception, while in 2. i'd understand it as a statement of fact, i.e *the person is perceived to be X* versus *the person is X*

So i would add another word (slightly violating your single-word tag);

"What she says is automatically disregarded, because of her **perceived insignificance**."

or

"What she says is automatically disregarded, because she is **perceived as insignificant**."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be answered with only one word, honestly.

The media uses gravitas to describe politicians who have a lot of respect or political sway with other politicians even. I wouldn't use any of the words listed above to describe a human being who had the opposite of gravitas. I would call him/her [*feckless*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feckless), when the object is a human.

If the object is an object, I agree with frivolous or the other antonyms listed here.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest Trumpishness. Maybe not common use yet, but it will be. Someone recently said "out-Nixoned Nixon". Everybody knew what that meant.

Comment: You should support your answer by citing, e.g., a dictionary definition for your suggestion.

Comment: @V2Blast Firstly, please don't go posting comments beginning "You should ...". Secondly, some words are buildable from freely applicable morphemes and these words more often than not don't appear in dictionaries.

Comment: @Araucaria: I could just as easily make up a new word and suggest that instead, but it wouldn't be a good answer if it was entirely unsupported as this answer is.

Comment: This is a site for linguists and therefore the valid and creative use of the freely productive morpheme will be both appreciated and readily understood and therefore this needs no other suppport than its own existence.

Answer (score -4):

A favorite phrase I have seen used to describe people with the opposite of gravitas is to call them, basically a non-entity.

I think the description best suited to your needs is *Mundane* meaning supremely ordinary.

Comment: You should support your answer by citing, e.g., dictionary definitions for your suggestions.